# Counting change of value in irregular time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time series data that looks like this:

```
Timestamp             Value
26/09/2013 17:00:00     1
26/09/2013 17:05:00     1
26/09/2013 17:08:41     1
26/09/2013 17:38:43     1
26/09/2013 17:49:55     0
26/09/2013 17:49:57     1
```

I want to convert it to a regular time series (15m), with a count of the number of times the value has changed in the 15m period. So something like this

```
End Timestamp         Value at End   Times Changed
26/09/2013 17:15:00       1              0
26/09/2013 17:30:00       1              0
26/09/2013 17:45:00       1              0
26/09/2013 18:00:00       1              2
```

I have looked at Pandas and I can't figure out how to do this.

A bit of context might help. This is SCADA (sensor) data - and the 1's and 0's correspond to a state of equipment - e.g. a switch is open or closed. The SCADA system reports the current value when it changes, but also it irregularly polls and reports the current value at that point in time (which may not have changed).

What I want to do is get the data into a form it can be loaded into a database and we can start querying which switches are changing state frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but it works:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

time_vec =     [datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,0,0)
               ,datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,5,0) 
               ,datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,8,41)     
               ,datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,38,43)
               ,datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,49,55)
               ,datetime.datetime(2013,9,26,17,49,57)]
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1,0,1],index = time_vec,columns=['value'])

df['count_change']=0
df.ix[df.value!=df.value.shift(1),'count_change']=1
df.ix[0,'count_change']=0

df.resample('15min',how={'value': 'last', 'count_change': 'sum'},fill_method='ffill',label='right')
```

Edit:

I just realized you may only want to forward fill the value column in intervals with no data, but not the count_change column (although in this specific example it doesn't change anything). A workaround could be:

```
df.resample('15min',how={'value': 'last', 'count_change': 'sum'},label='right').fillna(value={'count_change':0}).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Great hack - added some updates since ix is deprecated: df.loc[df.value!=df.value.shift(1), "count_change"] = 1, df.loc['2013-09-26 17:00:00','count_change'] = 0